# Installing Huawei dongle in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, usb-modem

I have question. I tried for many days to install my Huawei Dongle E153 on to my computer with OS Ubuntu. But I had no success. Can anyone help me to do it.

I'm a total Ubuntu novice.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the cd, it doesn't need it. You can just plug it in and go to your network connections and enable it.